# Can't parse JSON file - Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've created json file using Visual studio:

```
{
  "test":  "asd"
}
```

Using this code to read it:

```
 var test = fs.readFileSync('./files/test.json')
 var obj = JSON.parse(test);
```

which results in error: `Unexpected token ﻿ in JSON at position 0`

When I try to read package.json, it is read correctly. Does anyone know why I can't read my file?

Comment: Are you sure the path to the file is correct?

Comment: Try print out your `test`

Comment: It looks like you've got a foreign character at the beginning of that file

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but remember that you can `require` JSON files in node.js, this will save you having to use `fs.readFileSystem` and `JSON.parse`: `var obj = require('./files/test.json')`.

Comment: @weigreen test is uint8Array

Comment: @Raston, it actually returns a buffer. You can JSON.parse a buffer to get a json object.

Comment: @Raston, assuming your file is created exactly as stated above, it should work. Try to re-create your test.json file using copy / paste from your code above.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options

#### add `encoding` option

```
var test = fs.readFileSync('./files/test.json', {encoding: 'utf8'})
var obj = JSON.parse(test);
```

> If the encoding option is specified then this function returns a string. Otherwise it returns a buffer.

#### require json

```
var obj = require('./files/test.json');
```

> As of node v0.5.x yes you can require your JSON just as you would require a js file.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code help u

> $.getJSON("/files/test.json", function(json) {
>
> alert(json['test'])
>   //if massage show 'object object' then firs purse
>   //json=JSON.parse(json) //alert(json['test']) });

Answer (score 0):

Solution of the problem is opening file in notepad++ and saving it without BOM. Looks like json created via visual studio adds BOM

Answer (score -2):

It looks like this is not properly formatted JSON. They modifying it like this.

```
var myObject = {
        'test': 'asd'
    };
```

and then you parse would be....

```
 var obj = JSON.parse(myObject);
```

Comment: JSON.parse takes a ***string*** not an ***object***